# Taxonomy terms with the same name are updated between separate custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have 3 custom post types, and they each have a taxonomy labelled `location`, with some term names shared between them. The problem is, if I update a term name in any of the 3 custom post types, it updates the other 2 also, if the same term name is found. This also happens for the slug of the term

Each is registered with different names, so for example:

1. location-A
2. location-B
3. location-C

They each have also been assigned to completely different post types. Their slugs are also different. The only thing that's really the same is the locations labels in the admin menus.

Normally I wouldn't mind the names updating across each of the taxonomies, but it's causing a headache when limiting search results to each post type. I'm getting posts showing up where they shouldn't.

I have also tested this with a another taxonomy, and their shared term names also update each other. It seems to be the naming of the term that's the issue.

Is this a bug or am I overlooking it too much? can you just not have 2 terms, in completely different taxonomies and post types with the same name/slug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found a ticket on the trac. It's a bug and has been around for quite some time (~4 years). Hopefully it's fixed soon http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5809

Answer (score 0):

I also have right now same issue.
This is not a bug. 
Ex. If you want to filter 2 different 'custom post type' example 'bed_post' and 'chair_post' by taxonomy 'metal' you can use same name for them. If not use different name.

Remember that you can use same slug with different taxonomy name.

```
 $furniture->register_taxonomy(array(
  'taxonomy_name' => 'furniture-material', // here is name of taxonomy
  'singular' => 'Material',
  'plural' => 'Materials',
  'slug' => 'material' // here is slug
```

));

```
$furniture->register_taxonomy(array(
  'taxonomy_name' => 'floor-material', // here is name of taxonomy
  'singular' => 'Floor material',
  'plural' => 'Floor materials',
  'slug' => 'material' // here is slug
```

));